# Is mixed ANOVA suitable?

Tags: anova

I have two treatments and one group of participants (N = 26). I carried out 4 measures over the course of 10 weeks; each treatment happened in 2 weeks-ish. My independent factor has two levels (treatment 1 and 2). Since there were several measures, time is considered within-subject independent factor. In an attempt to compare the possible effects of the two treatments on three dependent variables (all continuousO, I'm just thinking one-way mixed ANOVA should be used. But honestly I'm not too sure. Any suggestions folks? Thanks.